# UTF-8 Encoding in text files from public rails folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

On my local environment + heroku production, I have a problem with UTF-8 encoding within an internally linked textfile.

Rails: 4.1.0

The textfile is in my public folder.
When linking to the file internally, it opens the file but the text is not correctly formatted and looks like this: http://www.wobleibtmeinhonorar.de/wobleibtmeinhonorar-pm-050514.txt

I have followed some stackoverflow advise and added

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

to my application.rb but that did not have any effect.
Also adding

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

to the header did not work.
What can I do to correctly encode this file?

Comment: what is wrong with the file? It openes in my browser

Comment: Check the formatting. E.g. "fÃ¼r" instead of "für".

Comment: # Internetprojekt für geprellte Kultur- und Kreativunternehmer startet --it is OK isnt it? check your browser encoding. Mine is chrome with utf 8